# How can i replace this?

Tags: java, android

How can I replace this

```
String str = "KMMH12DE1433";
String pattern = "^[a-z]{2}([0-9]{2})[a-z]{1,2}([0-9]{4})$";
String str2 = str.replaceAll(pattern, "repl");
Log.e("Founded_words2",str2);
```

What I got: KMMH12DE1433

What I want: MH12DE1433

Comment: Well, you're using `^` and `$` which will anchor to the beginning and the end of the input respectively.

Comment: Also `[a-z]` can't match uppercase letters, unless you explicitly use case-insensitive flag.

Comment: and replacing with "repl" will not quite give you the result you need either

Comment: For extracting the machting part from the input string you'll be better of with compiling a Pattern, creating a Matcher. perform find() on the matcher and then use group() to get to your required data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this using a proper `java.util.regex.Pattern` and a `java.util.regex.Matcher`:

```
    String str = "KMMH12DE1433";
    //Make the pattern, case-insensitive using (?i)
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)[a-z]{2}([0-9]{2})[a-z]{1,2}([0-9]{4})");
    //Create the Matcher
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(str);
    //Check if we find anything
    if(m.find()) {
        //Use what you found - with proper capturing groups you 
        //gain access to parts of your pattern as needed 
        System.out.println("Found this: " + m.group());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to remove the first two characters and if the first two characters will always be uppercase letters:

```
String str = "KMMH12DE1433";
String pattern = "^[A-Z]{2}";
String str2 = str.replaceAll(pattern, "");
Log.e("Output string: ", str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    String a = "KMMH12DE1433";
    String pattern = "^[A-Z]{2}";
    String rs = a.replaceAll(pattern,"");
```

Comment: Can you explain why this and not that?

Answer (score 0):

Please change like this

```
String ans=str.substring(0);
```